# Odd use of で in だめで

Tags: grammar, song-lyrics

I recently came across the following in the lyrics for a song:

「きみが　すきで　すきで　でもああ　ああ　だけど　だめで　だめで　うまくいかない」

It seems strange that で instead of だ is used after すき and だめ. Is there a reason for using で here, or is this just a quirk of the song writer?

Comment: Have you learned the te-form of na-adjectives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The で after だめ is exactly the same as the で after すき: the connective form or (a.k.a. "-te form" ) of だ/です.

If you replace all the で in your sentence with だ...

> きみがすきだ。すきだ。でも、ああ、ああーだけど、だめだ。だめだ。うまくいかない。

...you still have valid Japanese, but spread over 5 sentences instead of 1.